# ECharts Gauge : stacking values

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I was wondering how, if even possible, I can stack 2 gauge values like we can do with stacked bar chart.
The scheduled and completed values should be stacked together so 'completed' comes first, and  'scheduled' comes after, going all the way to 21 on the axis, instead of 12 now.

[image: Gauge]

I tried looking into radial bar chart, but this one can only do 360 degrees, and pie charts, which works with transparency, both not good solutions.

I think I can get it done using ChartJS, but I'd like to stick to 1 library.

Comment: Did you every conquer this problem? I have a similar need.

Comment: I ended up using the pie chart (with limiting the radius of each series) not the best solution but it kind of works, labeling is a pain though, not ideal. 
                    
    type: 'pie',
    radius: ['60%', '70%'],
    center: center,
    startAngle: 180,